# Argument passed is not favored over default implementation in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, constructor-injection

I would like to prefer the parameter implementation over an implementation registered by default, but it does not work.

- In fact, [the documentation suggests that it should work](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-Dependencies-Are-Resolved.ashx)

#### Demo of Incorrect Preference

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PassParamThatsAlreadyRegisteredAtResolutionTime();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PassParamThatsAlreadyRegisteredAtResolutionTime()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Passing argument that is already registered 
                    does not take precedence over the default implementation");
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<ISimpletonManager>()
                     .ImplementedBy<SimpletonManager>()
                     .LifestyleTransient()
                     .Properties(PropertyFilter.IgnoreAll));
        container.Register(Component.For<ISimpleton>().UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
                                     new Simpleton("Default Implementation"))
                                    .LifestyleTransient());
        // The above line could equally be the following, result is the same:
        // container.Register(Component.For<ISimpleton>()
        //                     .ImplementedBy<Simpleton>().LifestyleTransient());
        var runtimeConstructorParam = new Simpleton("Passed In Implementation");
        var runtimeArguments = new Arguments(
                                 new object[] {runtimeConstructorParam});
        var shouldBeManagerWithPassedInSimpleton = container
                             .Resolve<ISimpletonManager>(runtimeArguments);
        Console.WriteLine(shouldBeManagerWithPassedInSimpleton.Log);
    }
```

#### Console Output

```
Passing argument that is already registered
does not take precedence over the default implementation
Birth With Child Simpleton: Default Implementation
```

#### How to Invert the Preference?

- I need to be able to ignore the default registered dependency and instead Castle Windsor resolve using the supplied argument as the ISimpleton dependency?
- Do I need to implement my own [IDependencyResolver](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-Dependencies-Are-Resolved.ashx)? How?
- Or are [DynamicParameters](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-dependencies.ashx) useful here?

#### Supplied Dependency - Simpleton Class

```
public class Simpleton : ISimpleton
{
    public Simpleton(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

#### Resolved Type - SimpletonManager

```
public class SimpletonManager : ISimpletonManager
{
    private ISimpleton _child;

    public SimpletonManager(ISimpleton simpleton)
    {
        Child = simpleton;
    }

    public ISimpleton Child
    {
        get { return _child; }
        set
        {
            _child = value;
            Log = "Birth With Child Simpleton: " + Child.Id;
        }
    }

    public string Log { get; private set; }
}
```

---

[ [Using Castle.Core.dll and Castle.Windsor.dll 3.1.0 (2012-08-05)](http://www.castleproject.org/download/#windsor3) ]

Comment: you're passing an array of objects, while it seems that the Windsor people suggest either passing an IDictionary or an anonymous object - not sure if that makes any difference though: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Passing-Arguments.ashx

Comment: @JoannaTurban the Arguments class is actually a dedicated dictionary from the Windsor library and [creating it with an object array is what you find in the documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Arguments.ashx) - regardless, the exact same code works if using a non-generic parameter .. thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549577/failure-to-pass-generic-arguments-with-castle-windsor), the type of the dependency is different than the type that `Arguemnts` is exposing

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, i made a mess with the sample code before, i was tired :) I have updated the code to illustrate the issue, which is how can I make Castle Windsor prefer the dependency supplied at resolution time over the default implementation supplied at registration time? Basically, I need the registration-time implementation when no arguments are supplied at resolution time (the default), in fact i also need the registration-time implementation for completely different classes, but whenever I do supply an implementation at resolution-time I need Windsor to use that, which is not happening?

Comment: Wikid! The resolution came with `var runtimeArguments = new Arguments{{ typeof(ISimpleton), runtimeConstructorParam }};`